# Batch problem in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a script in MySQL that creates two tables, the second table references a field in the first table, now when I try to run this script in one batch it returns an error. My guess is that it checks the referenced table in the second table definition before creating the tables.

Any idea how I can create both tables at once?

Thanks

Edit:

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    FID INT NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (FID) REFERENCES table1 (ID)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If I create the first table, then create the second table everything works fine, but when I run this in one batch it returns an error

**Update:
It seems that this problem has been solved with MySQL 5.5. It now works correctly in one batch even if you have foreign key constraints in some table definitions.**

Comment: Can you give some sample code to show what you're trying to do?

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: I just pasted your example statement, and they work as-is. The error message may be helpful.

Comment: @Autocracy, I'm creating this in a .net app that uses the MySQL .NET Provider, the MySQL command line will work because it will execute the first statement immediately after the semi-colon + Carriage Return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simple thing , to create first the 2 tables,
after that do alter table and add the reference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this will make my script look ugly but it seems like the only way